# Diophantine solution set for $\frac{n(n-1)}2 = b(b-1)$

Tags: diophantine-equations

By [Diophantine solution set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) I mean solutions where `n` and `b` are integers.

I have one solution I found by trial and error but would like to find out how to generate them.

One solution is n=21, b=15.

Additionally I am only interested in solution where n > b and n and b are both positive.

Can be refactored = 1/2 = (b^2-b)/(n^2-n)

Comment: Note that it is just $(2n-1)^2=2\cdot(2b-1)^2-1$, a sort of Pell's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation reduces to $(2n-1)^2-2(2b-1)^2 = -1$ which is a generalized pell-equation. If you plug $x= 2n-1$ and $y = 2b-1$, the equation is equivalent to
$$ x^2-2y^2 = -1$$

Notice that $(x_0,y_0) = (7,5)$ is the minimal solution and the other solutions are obtained by the formula 
$$(x_n , y_n) = (3x_{n-1}+4y_{n-1} , 2x_{n-1}  +3y_{n-1})$$
Now just notice that by induction, all these solutions are odd, so we can plug $n$ and $b$ back in. By the theory op Pell's equations, these are the only solutions.